# Possible to set "Ack Immediately" using Solace Spring Cloud Stream Binder?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, solace

Per https://solace.com/blog/inside-a-solace-message-using-header-properties,
we are able to set properties like "ack immediately" to the message header.
And related API can be found in the Solace Messaging API (com.solacesystems.jcsmp).

However, from the Solace SCSt Binder doc,

https://github.com/SolaceProducts/solace-spring-cloud/tree/master/solace-spring-cloud-starters/solace-spring-cloud-stream-starter#solace-headers

I cannot find the corresponding header name for "ack immediately" above.
(but other properties like "ttl", "redelivered", "dmq Eligible" can be found)
Is it possible to set the "ack immediately" over Solace SCSt Binder?

If not, any work-around using SCSt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently setting "ack immediately" is not supported by the Spring Cloud Stream binder, it also isn't supported by some of the Solace APIs. It would be great to understand more with what you are trying to achieve by setting this parameter and if you are a Solace supported customer I'd suggest opening a support ticket requesting the feature as it would help get this prioritized.

Note that if you aren't changing the Publish Window Size (PUB_ACK_WINDOW_SIZE) which defaults to 1, then you effectively already have ackImmediately enabled since

> the event broker should send an acknowledgment for the messages received in the publish window when a threshold of either a **third of the Publish Window Size is reached** or one second has elapsed"

If you are trying to tune ackImmediately to get more throughput and haven't already tried adjusting the publish window size then I'd suggest starting there :)

Comment: I am trying to get more throughput and tried the publish window size already. So wanna check if "ack immediately" can further improve by removing the msg in the pub ack window quicker.

Comment: Set your pub ACK window size to 5.  That's the largest that would still cause the broker to ACK immediately.  (1/3rd window size, integer division rounds down, 5/3 = 1 msg... but a size of 6 means you'd need 2 messages to trigger an ACK).  Note that ACK immediately won't help throughput at all... it might hurt it a bit... it just means your publisher could receive it's async publish ACK quicker.  https://solace.com/blog/understanding-guaranteed-message-publish-window-sizes-and-acknowledgement/